# Android GridView redraw all item when one item is selected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a GridView with all the items having imageView. When one is selected, I see all the items get refresh because there is getView call for each items.
Why this happens? I see GridView get refresh every time. Below is call stack.

```
getView
obtainView:AsbsListView
makeAndAddView: GridView
makeRow:GridView
fillDown:GridView
fillSpecific:GridView
layoutChildren:GirdView
onLayout: AbsListView
layout:View
layout:ViewGroup
onLayout:RelativeLayout
....

    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/my_gridview"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:listSelector="@color/TEST_RED"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loading"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"/>
```

onItemClick doesn't do invalidateViews. It does nothing actually.

Comment: It seems it is designed in that way. If one item get clicked, all items need do getView(). To avoid image reload, use tag for image view is the way.